# Do ssl certificates apply to the server or the hostname?

Tags: apache, iis, ssl

Im new to hosting sites with ssl certificates and i wanted to know, if the server is running an iis server with a site and i now install apache on the same server, does the certificate apply to both hosts and if not, if i use the same dns/site address will it then apply?

After the responces i have gotten i would like to add that in order to run apache and iis i have to change the port number of the apache site, does the cert apply to this, so if iis is host www.123.co.za and apache www.123.co.za:8080 - does the cert apply, espicially considering ssl is on its own port ??

Answer (score 2):

On the conceptual side, an SSL certificate establishes identity; that is it verifies that the person or organization who owns a particular domain name (hostname) approves of the actual server that the client is communicating with. Thus, the certificate itself is not tied to any particular server, but it is tied to a hostname or set of hostnames (for example, a `*.example.com` certificate would be valid for `www.example.com` and `test.example.com`.

On the practical side, if both server programs are set up with the certificate, and both have domain names within the scope of the certificate, it should work just fine.

Comment: But now if i have site www.123.co.za on iis i have to have www.123.co.za:diff port number on apache. does the cert still apply? or does it depend on the cert you have?

Answer (score 1):

An SSL certificate in this context is used to certify the **host name**. As long as you have the *key pair* and the certificate, you should be able to use the same certificate in IIS, Apache or any other SSL server.

You will however run into problems if you want to run several sites under different host names on the same ip and tcp port.

So, from a technical point it should be perfectly possible to use the same certificate in IIS running on  `www.123.co.za:443` and Apache running on `www.123.co.za:9443`.

Comment: That is not completely right. There are some certificate authorities that sell server-bound certificates, e.g. you can't use those certificates on more than one server.

Comment: But now if i have site www.123.co.za on iis i have to have www.123.co.za:diff port number on apache. does the cert still apply?

Comment: @sanmai: Interesting, could you add more details or update your answer? I have never seen that, and am curious about what fields in the certificate is used to enforce this.

Comment: @anders-lindahl For example, VeriSign certificates are valid for up to five servers. This isn't an uncommon thing. Dunno how they enforce it if they do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on type of your certificate (is it a wildcard certificate?) and a license you bought it under.

As far as I can see a typical cheap certificate apply for any ports on the host it is issued for. So, yes, `www.example.com` and `www.example.com:8080` can both use same certificate.